# Почему switch-case не позволяет использовать более одного nameof()

Tags: c#, строки, switch

Есть команда:

```
public string Code { get; set; }
```

И есть конструкция

```
switch (A.Code)
{
    case nameof(B.X.Code):
        break;
    case nameof(B.Y.Code):
        break;
}
```

Без `nameof()` использовать case нельзя, т.к. строка `public`...

НО! При компиляции получаю ошибку:

```
Duplicate case label value ""Code""
```

---

Если же написать вообще без nameof():

```
switch (A.Code)
{
    case B.X.Code:
        break;
    case B.Y.Code:
        break;
}
```

То выдает ошибку:

```
A constant value is expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поймите, чтобы использовать switch/case с типом `string`, вы должны знать что точно передаётся в это свойство. Например, в `Code` передаются 3 разных строки: abc, acb, bca (просто как пример). Тогда можно сделать так:

```
switch (A.Code)
    {
        case "abc":
            break;
        case "acb":
            break;
        case "bca":
            break;
    }
```

Если тип вашего свойства нельзя менять, то тогда вам надо написать столько кейсов, сколько значений будет принимать ваше свойство. Или написать парочку кейсов, а все остальные обрабатывать через `default`

Другой путь - это использовать `enum`. 
Например

```
    enum CodeType
    {
        Code1,
        Code2,
        Code3
    }
```

А свойство у вас будет

```
public CodeType Code { get; set; }
```

И легко использовать в switch/case

```
switch (A.Code)
{
    case CodeType.Code1:
        break;
    case CodeType.Code2:
        break;
    case CodeType.Code3:
        break;
}
```

Comment: функцию Code править нельзя по разным причинам

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG увидел ваш комментарий и добавил описание, если нельзя править свойство

Comment: Спасибо, понял...

Answer (score 3):

`nameof` - получает имя передаваемой параметром переменной, т.е. на выходе получается что-то типа:

```
switch (A.Code)
{
    case "Code":
        break;
    case "Code":
        break;
}
```

что, согласитесь, ерунда.

Comment: И как исправить?

Comment: Зависит от того, чего вы вообще хотите  - пока выглядит как какая-то дичь)

Comment: Хотел бы подставлять значение из Code. Но public параметр string сделать это не дает

Comment: Все еще не понял, причем тут паблик?

Comment: Сек, сейчас дополню вопрос - станет попонятней

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG используйте enum вместо string

Comment: @Саму функцию Code править нельзя по разным причинам

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Все еще не понятно чего вы хотите - да вам компилятор правильно говорит - то что содержится в case - должно быть константой на момент компиляции. Еще раз повторю - каковы ваши намерения?

Comment: Я хочу взять код или подтипа A или подтипа B и если код A.Code совпадает c кодом подтипа A, то далее выполнить определенные действия, если же A.Code совпадает c кодом подтипа B то выполнить другие действия

Comment: ну используйте if

Comment: Там слишком много if получится в итоге (около 8к). Хотелось бы, чтобы все было по полочкам, а не куча if-else

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, а 8 case в switch - это норм? :)

Comment: @Grundy получше

Comment: Свитч для этого точно не годится.

Comment: ок-ок, тогда спасибо